# How to retrieve user story and its relevant source code from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

My target is to pick up the source code directly from the user story associated with it. How to retrieve these details, using Azure DevOps API, I am able to find changesets and work items related to it till now.. but how to access other code components for an user story.

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: You have given an api for commit change.  But what I need is an user story and its all code files.  For eg. for a user story, to develop it if it needs 10 files, I need list of all the 10 files for a particular user story.  Please help me with the API for that or procedure for that.

Comment: Hi, Just get the 10 file name instead of the commit content, is it right?

Comment: If yes, check the step a and b, just add foreach, then we could list the file path.

Comment: Does it mean that each work item will have only one commit?

Comment: Yes, I need all the file names for a single work item.  Please help me with it.

Comment: Notice the first pic, if we add commits to the work item, the link type is ArtifactLink, we could list all link commit URL via the link type, please wait, I will update the answer.

Comment: Hi, do you mind list the file names via power shell script?

Comment: No, I am trying to do it via Azure DevOps python API.

Comment: If you could give powershell script also, it would be fine.

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: One more query.  If a workitem has more than one commits and if all the commits has some files in common, we need only the files that got commited latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a**. Get commit info for the specified work item ID, notice the field **relations**, it contain the link commit ID, repo ID and project ID. The format is: `vstfs:///Git/Commit/{Project ID}%2F{Repo ID}%2F{Commit ID}`

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/v-viliu/test/_apis/wit/workitems/106?$expand=1&api-version=6.1-preview.3
```

Result:

[image]

**b.** Get [commit path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) via the commit ID

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=5.0
```

Power shell Script:

```
cls


$PAT="{pat}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
          
#List commit ID via work item ID
$GetWorkItemURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/wit/workitems/{work Item ID}?" + "$" + "expand=1&api-version=6.1-preview.3"
$GetWorkItemResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetWorkItemURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get 


#List all commit path
foreach($LinkDetails in $GetWorkItemResult.relations) {
    if ($LinkDetails.rel -match "ArtifactLink") { 
        $DetailInfo = $LinkDetails.url -split'(%2F)'
        $CommitID = $DetailInfo[4]
        $RepoID = $DetailInfo[2]
        #Write-Host $CommitID
        #Write-Host $RepoID
        $GetCommitPathURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/repositories/$($RepoID)/commits/$($CommitID)/changes?api-version=5.0"
        #Write-Host $GetCommitPathURL
        $GetCommitPathResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetCommitPathURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get 
        Write-Host $GetCommitPathResult.changes[-1].item.path
    }
}
```

Work item link info and the structure of the project

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am yet to complete the solution.  Once I finish the solution, will accept your answer.  Sorry for the delay.  So far it looks perfect.

Comment: How to retrieve user story and its relevant source code filenames from Azure DevOps tfvc?